# Regular Expression to search for destructors without virtual

Tags: regex

My goal is to search my code base for all destructors that aren't virtual (ie C++). The interpreter my search tool is using is Perl style. I'm not a regex power user but I've cobbled something together that sort of works.

```
^(?<!\bvirtual)\s*~[A-Za-z_]+\(\)
```

The problem is that it doesn't work in every case. In particular, I cannot make it ignore the virtual unless it is at the start of the line. I don't want to make assumptions about spacing/tabs, or where the destructor appears in the line, so I'd like to do better.

Below are some test cases and desired outcomes:

```
virtual func1();    ~class1(); virtual func2();   // Should match
virtual func1();~class2();virtual func2();        // Should match
~xyz();                                           // Should match
  ~abc();                                         // Should match
virtual    ~abc();                                // Should fail
virtual~def();                                    // Should fail
```

I've tried a few different approaches. I'm currently struggling with '~' not being a word character (so I cannot test for word boundaries) but I also cannot use non-fixed width quantifiers in lookarounds (for the whitespace).

Time to look for help. Any ideas?

Comment: Try this: '(?<=^|;)\s*~destructor'  (without quotes). It should do what you want (just Trim the match)

Comment: I modified it a little bit since I'm not searching for the exact word "desctructor".
```
(?<=^|;)\s*~[A-Za-z_]+\(\)
```
I'm getting "invalid lookbehind assertion encountered in the regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative look ahead that excludes "virtual" over any number of non-brackets after start of input or semi-colon:

```
(^|;(?!$))((?!virtual)[^()])*~destructor\(\);
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/LCb4r8ezSNHn20).

The crux here is the fragment `((?!virtual)[^()])`. `[^()]` matches any non-bracket and `(?!virtual)` ensures the at no point along the way does it move past the character sequence `virtual` when a quantifier is added.

Comment: Ok. I think this did it. I wasn't searching for "destructor" specifically, but I can figure out the rest.
Technically, it does match for anything in between "virtual" and the "~", but that's acceptable.
This is what I went with:  `(^|;(?!$))((?!virtual)[^()])*~\s*[A-Za-z_]+\s*\(\s*\)\s*;`
Now I just need to stare at this a while a figure out what it all means!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example with PHP:

```
<?php
$s1 = <<<eof
virtual func1();    ~destructor(); virtual func2();   // Should match
virtual func1();~destructor();virtual func2();        // Should match
~destructor();                                        // Should match
  ~destructor();                                      // Should match
virtual    ~destructor();                             // Should fail
virtual~destructor();                                 // Should fail
eof;
$a = explode("\n", $s1);
foreach ($a as $s2) {
   $n = preg_match('/(^|;) *~destructor\(\);/', $s2);
   if ($n !== 0) {
      echo $s2, "\n";
   }
}
```